# C# - Why does Form has multiline Title?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Heyyy Guys,

i was writing a new program in c# where a string is been read out of a resource, (.txt) but when i set the externalized string as the forms title it seems to have 2 lines. I believe this is because of the externalization of the string, but i have a command wich shall remove the new line. Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Language
{
    public class Language_Reader
    {
        private static CultureInfo ci = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

        private static int word_count = 2;

        private static string[] string_array;
        private static string temp_string;
        private static char[] remove_chars = {'\n'};

        public static void makeLanguageStrings() {
            if((ci.Name == "en-Us") || (ci.Name == "en-AU") || (ci.Name == "en-BZ") || (ci.Name == "en-CA") || (ci.Name == "en-CB") || (ci.Name == "en-IE") || (ci.Name == "en-JM") || (ci.Name == "en-NZ") || (ci.Name == "en-PH") || (ci.Name == "en-ZH") || (ci.Name == "en-TT") || (ci.Name == "en-GB") || (ci.Name == "en-ZW")) 
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Loading Resource: English");
                //Loading resource
                temp_string =      Minecraft_Texturepack_Reload.Properties.Resources.Englisch;
                Debug.WriteLine("Succeed to load resource.");
                //splitting up resource into array
                Debug.WriteLine("Splitting up upper resource into string[]");
                string_array = temp_string.Split(remove_chars);
                for(int i = 0; i < word_count; i++) {

                    string_array[i].Trim(remove_chars);

                    //setting Language_Strings strings
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        Language_Strings.main_form_Text = string_array[i];
                    }
                    if(i == 1) 
                    {
                        Language_Strings.project_menu_item_Text = string_array[i];
                    }

                }
                Debug.WriteLine("Succeeded to set strings' texts");
            }

            if((ci.Name == "de-DE")) {
                Debug.WriteLine("Loading Resource: Deutsch");
                //Loading resource
                temp_string = Minecraft_Texturepack_Reload.Properties.Resources.Deutsch;
                Debug.WriteLine("Succeed to load resource.");
                //splitting up resource into array
                Debug.WriteLine("Splitting up upper resource into string[]");
                string_array = temp_string.Split(remove_chars);
                for (int i = 0; i < word_count; i++)
                {

                    string_array[i].Trim(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());

                    //setting Language_Strings strings
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        Language_Strings.main_form_Text = string_array[i];
                    }
                    if (i == 1)
                    {
                        Language_Strings.project_menu_item_Text = string_array[i];
                    }

                }
                Debug.WriteLine("Succeeded to set strings' texts");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[The form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYl4A.png)

I can't understand why theres still an new line. Please Help!

Comment: Trim doesn't modify the original string; it *returns* the modified string. You need to assign the result back to the array.

Comment: I would use string_array[i] = string_array[i].Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty) on the first line in the for loop.

Comment: string_array[i] = string_array[i].Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty) doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about instead of this line:

```
temp_string =      Minecraft_Texturepack_Reload.Properties.Resources.Englisch;
```

just this:

```
var reader = new StringReader(Minecraft_Texturepack_Reload.Properties.Resources.Englisch);
Language_Strings.main_form_Text = reader.ReadLine()
Language_Strings.project_menu_item_Text = reader.ReadLine();
```

And delete the code:

```
Debug.WriteLine("Succeed to load resource.");
            //splitting up resource into array
            Debug.WriteLine("Splitting up upper resource into string[]");
            string_array = temp_string.Split(remove_chars);
            for(int i = 0; i < word_count; i++) {

                string_array[i].Trim(remove_chars);

                //setting Language_Strings strings
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    Language_Strings.main_form_Text = string_array[i];
                }
                if(i == 1) 
                {
                    Language_Strings.project_menu_item_Text = string_array[i];
                }

            }
            Debug.WriteLine("Succeeded to set strings' texts");
```

Same change for Deutsch (German).

Then I would suggest to refactor to inject a language handler, but that is just my picky self :)

Answer (score 0):

Refactored your code. Not sure why you were using temp strings or why you were using a loop to get an index of `0` and `1` when it will always be the same.

This should remove any new line characters. Please let me know if this doesn't work.

```
    public static void makeLanguageStrings()
    {
        switch (ci.Name)
        {
            case "en-Us":
            case "en-AU":
            case "en-BZ":
            case "en-CA":
            case "en-CB":
            case "en-IE":
            case "en-JM":
            case "en-NZ":
            case "en-PH":
            case "en-ZH":
            case "en-TT":
            case "en-GB":
            case "en-ZW":
                string_array = Minecraft_Texturepack_Reload.Properties.Resources.Englisch.Split(Environment.NewLine).Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty);
                break;
            case "de-DE":
                string_array = Minecraft_Texturepack_Reload.Properties.Resources.Deutsch.Split(Environment.NewLine).Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty);
                break;
        }
        Language_Strings.main_form_Text = string_array[0];
        Language_Strings.project_menu_item_Text = string_array[1];
    }
```